# db2 express c mac osx

Tags: db2, mac-os-x

I'm experiencing some troubles with the execution of DB2 express c on Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard.

I have installed the db system, creating two users, db2 and db2-user. The latter is the instance owner. I have sourced db2profile and the env variables seem to be set correctly.

Db2 starts successfully, but I'm not able to run db2sampl, the error is:

```
Attempt to start DB2 instance failed.
SQL1019N  The node name "db2-user" specified in the command is not valid.
```

I have googled the error and it looks like I have to change the DB2INSTANCE variable, but I do not know what value should be.

Comment: Did what I suggest work?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to change `DBINSTANCE`. All that does is change what instance is the "main" one for your OS. And you only have one instance from what I understand (named db2 I believe). I'm betting this has more to do with permissions as you are attempting to run db2sampl, which I believe creates the sample database if I remember correctly. Instance owner should be able to run this without any issues.

If I were you, I would run db2sampl as instance owner and then perform your necessary `GRANT`s for db2-user once the database is there.